# Sharedpreferences Don't Work (Between 2 activitiy)

Tags: android

I have 2 activity. In "A" activity I have a button. When user click this button, in "B" activity long data will change. If user don't click button long data change standard "61000" long data. When I try to do it my app closing...

A activity code;

```
SharedPreferences paylasim = getSharedPreferences("sure", MODE_PRIVATE);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = paylasim.edit();
              editor.putLong("veri", 31000);
              editor.commit();
```

B activity code;

```
SharedPreferences paylasim = getSharedPreferences("sure", MODE_PRIVATE); 
long kalansure = paylasim.getLong("veri", 61000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my app closing"?

Comment: An error occuring. "Unfortunately it stopped"

Comment: Always show the stack trace when that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't quite understand what you are asking, I think I have encountered similar situations before.

First, let me paraphrase your question,

> I try to save a long value in ActivityA, and I want to retrieve it in Activity B by clicking a button. But when I click the button, the app crashes.

When I first used `SharedPreferences` to store data across activities, it didn't even save the data! Then I found out the `PreferenceManager` class so I used that class and the whole thing works. See if this works for you.

To put stuff in SP,

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
    .putLong("someKey", someValue).apply();
```

To get stuff,

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .getLong("somekey", someDefaultValue);
```

where `this` is a `Context`.

But you don't actually need to store the data in `SharedPreferences` if you just want to pass some data from Activity A to Activity B. (I think that's what you *actually* want to do) You just need to call `putExtra` on the intent object that you create to navigate to Activity B:

```
Intent i = ...;
i.putExtra("someKey", someValue);
startActivity(i);
```

Then, in Activity B, get the stuff back:

```
getIntent().getExtra().getLong("someKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had allready used the "veri" key to store data of other type (Integer for example) then you would get a cast exception and your app would close. Make sure that is not the case.

Other than that you should post the log cat output. Otherwise anything anyone says is just a guess